# Trying to create an instance of an object dynamically

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

Getting The following Error...

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'CSV_OOP_Convert.FileConverter'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a
>   cast?)    \server\UserShares\DBell\VSC\CSV_OOP_Convert\CSV_OOP_Convert\Form1.cs  44  39  CSV_OOP_Convert

```
String className = cmbConversionAlgorithm.Text;
string namespaceName = "CSV_OOP_Convert";

FileConverter myObj =Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));
ConvertFile(myObj);
```

the cmbConversionAlgorithm contains the the correct name of the class I wish to create an instance of.

it works fine when I create it normally.

```
CSV_OOP_Convert.TFConverter tfc = new CSV_OOP_Convert.TFConverter();
```

Comment: `CreateInstance` returns an `object`, you need to cast: `FileConverter myObj =(FileConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(...)`

Answer (score 2):

[`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) returns an object of type `object`, so it’s a completely unspecific type. In order to assign that to a variable of a more specific type, you need to make an explicit type cast:

```
FileConverter myObj = (FileConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

Activator returns an Object

Try something like this:

```
String className = cmbConversionAlgorithm.Text;
string namespaceName = "CSV_OOP_Convert";

Object myObj =Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));

ConvertFile((FileConverter)myObj);
```

Comment: 4 equals answers... and its a Duplicate :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Cast result to FileConverter class

```
var myObj =Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className)) as FileConverter;
```